# Windows Phone 8 - Hiding status bar in Phonegap App, which is using jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, cordova, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to get a Phonegap-App to run on Windows Phone 8. My biggest problem right now is, that the hight of my app is calculated based on the height of the device. But this includes the WP8 status bar.

Since I need my footer to be at the exact bottom of my page, thus enabling the user to control my app, I was wondering if there is a way in Phonegap 3.1 to hide the status bar of windows phone or to tell jQuery Mobile that it needs to exclude the hight of the status bar. I tried setting the padding of the body and configure the app to run in fullscreen mode. Both things failed.

As always, happy for hints.

Answer (score 12):

I'd like to answer my own question for anyone who might encounter the same one. The solution is to open the

> MainPage.xaml

and replace the "true" in the following line so that

```
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True"
//BECOMES
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="False"
```

Afterwards the SystemTray, that's how it is called ;), won't show up again.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

The right approach would be to specify Fullscreen mode in config.xml. Copy following entry in the www\config.xml which will disable the status bar for all platforms.

```
<preference name="Fullscreen" value="true" />
```

Comment: Hey, by now the issue is fixed, so yes: This would be the right approach now. It did not work back then.

Comment: This is the true solution for phonegap